# Como medir a performance e custos (processamento e memória) de um frontend?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, desempenho

Estou trabalhando em um projeto que utiliza muito JavaScript (ecmascript-6, jQuery), Html5, CSS e gostaria de ter alguma forma de medir a **performance**, o consumo de **processamento** e  o consumo de **memória RAM**, para que, ao realizar alterações na forma de implementar, seja possível checar se melhorou ou piorou o desempenho da aplicação.

Notas:

- Não estou perguntando sobre boas práticas de otimização recomendadas pelo Google, Yahoo, Mozilla, Amazon, etc. (unificação e e minificação JavaScript ou CSS, utilização de cache, otimização de imagens, gzip, etc.), pois isso está  satisfatoriamente resolvido.
- Não estou considerando o tempo de download da página, está satisfatoriamente resolvido.
- Uma forma para medir o consumo em memória RAM é o gerenciador de tarefas do Google Chrome, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>, mas processamento não é mensurável adequadamente e não registra o histórico de consumo da memória RAM. Também não tenho referências de se estas medidas são confiáveis ou se não são.
- Também tem o recurso Profiles do Google Chrome DevTools (<kbd>F12</kbd>). Mas não achei prático para mensurar. Idem para o FireBug do Mozilla Firefox (<kbd>F12</kbd>).
- As ferramentas para desenvolvedor do Microsoft Edge (<kbd>F12</kbd>) são interessantes, mas ainda não parece ser a solução.

Como posso medir de forma prática e eficiente estas variáveis? Preferencialmente algo que registre valores máximos consumidos de CPU e memória RAM.

Para ilustrar: em PHP utilizo o [WebGrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind) para realizar estas análises. Gostaria muito de encontrar algo similar em JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

No Firefox você pode usar a extensão **Firebug**.

No Chrome, basta apertar <kbd>F12</kbd>.
Ainda sobre o Chrome, dẽ uma olhada nas abas:

- Network: para ver coisas relacionadas a rede
- Timeline: ver qual tipo de operação o browser está fazendo. Ex: executando um script (Scripting) ou pintando a tela (Painting)
- Profile: também mostra uso de CPU, além do uso de memória

Como tem muitas opções, sugiro dar uma olhada aqui:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/